# Express $e^\pi$ in the form $x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The hint for this problem says to reason carefully, so I did. However, whenever I see $e$ in a problem I'm never quite sure how to treat it.

My attempt:

$e^\pi$ is of the form $re^{i\theta}$, so

$$r= e^\pi$$
$$a=r\cos \theta$$
$$a=(e^\pi)\cos(\pi)$$
$$a=e^\pi$$

And,

$$b=r\sin\theta$$
$$b=0$$

Thus,

$$z=e^{\pi}$$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: @avid19 yup. Not much to it.

Comment: Can you say $e^{\pi} = \sqrt[i]{-1} = (-1)^{-i}$ ?

Comment: @Henry I don't think so....why?

Comment: ... because $\left(e^{\pi}\right)^i = -1$ is the most interesting thing about $e^{\pi}$

Comment: @Henry ok....? I don't follow

Comment: @Henry How come? It is well known that $(e^\pi)^i=-e^{-2\pi}$, no?

Comment: @Did: Perhaps you are missing an $i$ in the exponent of $-e^{-2\pi}$

Comment: @Henry No. Perhaps you are missing the point. Oh, and by the way, it is also well known that $(e^\pi)^i=-e^{42\pi}$...

Comment: @Did: Be like that then

Answer (score 2):

My pocket calculator gives $e^\pi\doteq23.14$. There is *absolutely no reason* that it could be something else in the complex world. Note that the "complex" function $z\mapsto e^z$ is the *extension* of the function $x\mapsto e^x$ defined for real $x$; hence $e^\pi$ remains $e^\pi$ even in the larger environment. Note that the formula
$$e^z:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1\over k!}\>z^k$$
is valid for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$, hence for all $z\in{\mathbb R}\subset{\mathbb C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is incorrect - one way to see this is that it gives the wrong result for $e^{\pi/2} \approx 4.81$: It would give a pure imaginary number.

---

$e^{\pi}$ is just a real number, since the exponent is real. Any real number $x$ can be written as $x + 0i$.

Comment: Can the same thing be said vice versa? If I had $e^i\pi$, could I simply say that the real part is $0$? Or is it different for the imaginary side of things?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: $e^{i\pi}=-1+0i$

Comment: $e^i$ is not a purely imaginary number, so no. (And neither is $e^{i\pi}$).

Comment: @T.Bongers wait so $2i$ is a purely imaginary number, but $e^i$ isn't??

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\Im\left(e^{\pi}\right)=0$ so the imaginary part of $e^{\pi}$ is $0$, what gives us it in the form:

$$x+yi\to e^{\pi}+0i$$